# Django: product model with multiple variations and pricing

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Crux of the problem: One product can have multiple variations with different prices.

For example: if a Shirt has 2 color choices (black and white) and 2 size choices (Small and Large), there will be 4 product variants, like below:

1. Shirt - Color: White, Size: Large, Price: $12,
2. Shirt - Color: White, Size: Small, Price: $10,
3. Shirt - Color: Black, Size: Large, Price: $14,
4. Shirt - Color: Black, Size: Small, Price: $10

Below is my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    """
    This model holds all common fields of a product
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155)


class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    """
    This model holds the attr_type (ex: color) and attribute_name (ex: red)
    """
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attr_type = models.ForeignKey(
        VariantType, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    attr_name = models.CharField(max_length=155, blank=True)


class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    """
    This model holds the values for price and combination of attributes
    """
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variant = models.ManyToManyField(ProductAttribute)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=155, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=2)
```

**I want to know 2 things:**

1. I have to save the product attributes first (ProductAttribute model) and then create specific m2m relations in the ProductVariant model. How do I do this?
2. Is there a better option for models than what I have created?

Comment: Actually what is the issue now?

Comment: I have to save the product attributes first (ProductAttribute model) and then create specific m2m relations in the ProductVariant model. How do I do this?

Comment: In you model product, you can add new attribute product_variants = ManyToMany(Productattribute, through=ProductVariant)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/